# Pairing among the members in same list in java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, logic

In problem statement, I have 'n' number of families with 'n' number of family members.

eg:

```
John jane (family 1)
tiya (family 2)
Erika (family 3)
```

I have to assign all members in such a way that person should not pair with the his family member. 
and output should be:

```
John => tiya
jane => Erika
tiya => jane
Erika => john
```

I have created the object `Person(name ,familyID, isAllocated)`. 
Created the list and added `personName_id` in this this.

I am thinking to use the map for association. So that `john_1` will be key and `tiya_2` will be value.

I am failing to associate those pairs through map. How can I shuffle the members it the list.

Also, It would be nice if anyone could suggest me the better solution.

**Code:**

Getting person:

```
public static List getperson()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = null;
    int count = 0;

    List <Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    while(!(line = keyboard.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
      String[] values = line.split("\\s+");
      //System.out.print("entered: " + Arrays.toString(values) + "\n");
      int familyid = count++;
      for(String name :values)
      {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFamilyId(familyid);
        person.setName(name);
        person.setAllocated(false);

        people.add(person);
      }
    }
    return people;
}
```

Mapping:

```
public static List mapGifts(List pesonList) 
{
    Map<String , String> personMap = new HashMap<String , String>();

    Iterator<Person> itr = pesonList.iterator();
    Iterator<Person> itr2 = pesonList.iterator();
    List<String> sender =  new ArrayList<>();

    while(itr.hasNext())
        {
          Person p = itr.next();

              sender.add(p.getName()+"_"+p.getFamilyId());
              personMap.put(p.getName()+"_"+p.getFamilyId(), "");
             // p.setAllocated(true);

        }

          while(itr2.hasNext())
          {
              /*if(p.isAllocated())
              {*/

              // Separate Sender name and id from sender list
              //check this id match with new p1.getFamilyId()

              for(String sendername :sender)
              {
                 // System.out.println("Sender "+sendername);
                  personMap.put(sendername, "");

              String[] names = sendername.split("_");
              String part1 = names[0]; // 004
              String familyId = names[1]; // 004


              Person p2 = itr2.next();
              System.out.println(p2.getFamilyId() +"   "+familyId +" "+p2.isAllocated());

              if(p2.isAllocated())
              {
                  for ( String value: personMap.values()) {
                        if ( value != sendername) {

                        }
                    }

              }
              if( p2.getFamilyId() != Integer.parseInt(familyId))
              {

              // add values in map
              }
              }

              break;
            //  Person newPerson = personLists.get(j);

          }

    for (Iterator it = personMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
    {
          Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
          Object key = entry.getKey();
          Object value = entry.getValue();

          System.out.println("Gifts "+key+"=>"+value);
        }
    return pesonList;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your relevant code.

Comment: One possible answer is you should produce all the possible answer of pairing the family together per each family. Reduce the ones that is the same pairing. If you like to know more, try mapping them as a item set something like A -> B, C, D; B-> C, D, C-> D (meaning A pairs with B, C ,D; B pairs with C, D and C->D)

Comment: Thanks @TingShunNg. But I have to map only one member in the list and he/she should not be in the same family. moreover I have to map every member in such a way that he/she should be sender and also receiver.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, you only care that you match people.  How they match doesn't matter.  That said, I'll assume you have a list of FamilyID's, and a list of names of everyone, and that you can sort the list of people according to family IDs.

Let's call them:

`List<FamilyID> families;` and 
`LinkedList<Person> people;`, respectively. (You can make FamilyID an enumerated class)

We need two hashmaps.  One to generate a list (essentially an adjacency list) of family members given a familyID:

`HashMap<FamilyID, List<Person>> familyMembers;` ,

and one to generate a list of sender(key) and receiver(value) pairs:

`HashMap<Person, Person> pairs;`

A useful function may be that, when given a person and their family ID, we can find the next available person who can receive from them.

`String generateReceiver(Person newSender, FamilyID familyID);`

Implementation of this method should be pretty straightforward.  You can iterate through the list of people and check to see if the current person is not a family member.  If that condition passes, you remove them from the "people" list so you don't try to iterate through them again.  If you're using a linked list for this, removal is O(1) since you'll already have the reference.  Worst case on traversals the list is n + n - 1 + ... + 2 times to get O(n^2) time efficiency (i.e. you have one large family and many small ones).  Work around that would be to ditch the LinkedList, use an Array-based list, and keep a separate array of index values corresponding to each "currently available receiver of a specified family". You'd initialize these values as you added the people from each family to the people list (i.e. start of family 1 is index "0"; if family 1 has 2 people, start of family 2 would be index "2").  This would make the function O(1) time if you just incremented the current available receiver index everytime you added a sender-receiver pair.  (Message me if you want more details on this!)

Last but not least, the loop is doing this for all people.

```
 for (List<Person> family : familyMembers)
  for (Person person : family)
   {
     // get the next available receiver who is not a family member
     // add the family member and its receiver to "pairs" hash
   }
```

Note that the above loop is pseudocode.  If you're wondering if you would generate conflicting receiver/senders with this method, you won't.  The list of people is essentially acting as a list of receivers.  Whichever way you implement the `people` list, the `generateReceiver(...)`eliminates the chance that the algorithm would see a faulty-receiver.  Per efficiency, if you do the array based implementation then you're at O(N) time for generating all pair values, where N is the total number of people.  The program itself would be O(N) space as well.

Of course, this is all based on the assumption you have enough people to match for sender-receiver pairs.  You'd need to add bells and whistles to check for special cases.

Hope this helps!  Good luck!